# How can I create a table in SQL only if a column in another table is true?

Tags: sql-server, database, constraints

For example, assume I want to create the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE Add_Friends(

PRIMARY KEY(email_1, email_2),
email_1 VARCHAR(50) FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Normal_Users,
email_2 VARCHAR(50) FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Normal_Users,
accepted_or_not BIT
)

CREATE TABLE Messages1(

message_ID INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
date_sent date,
message_content VARCHAR(100),
sender VARCHAR(50) FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Normal_Users,
reciever VARCHAR(50) FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Normal_Users
)
```

Users should only be able to send messages to each other if they are friends (the last column in Add_Friends). How can I define this constraint in the Messages1 table?

Comment: Do you create table on fly? One table per message/conversation/user? I hope not otherwise read [CREATE TABLE @tbl](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html#Cre_tbl)

Comment: No I dont. I only have one table for all conversations.

Comment: I would be inclined to manage this outside of the database in the application tier, this is not really data integrity, it is more business rules. If you use a foreign key to manager this you will end up with a situation where someone cannot "unfriend" someone because it will violate this foreign key constraint. You could have a stored procedure that first checks if users are friends before inserting the message, and raises an error if not, but this is about the extent to which I personally would handle this rule within the database.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly your question:

You don't need to create a table for each conversation, you can put all the messages together in the same table and id the conversation registering the primarykey from the add frinds.

I assume you have another table with all the data of your "persons" and then Add_Friends is the table where you add realtionsship between those persons, so to do the restriction you want you need to first check if the relationship between sender and reciever exist and then do an insert if the query returns a value.

```
SELECT ID_FRIEND 
FROM ADD_FRIENDS 
WHERE email_1 = "+ID_SENDER+" AND email_2 = "+ID_RECIEVER+"
```

If this query returns a value it means the realationship exist and you can do the insert.

Is better to do this in two steps so you can also restrict things like if the person is or not registed, online status or even be able to write a message in the first place.

And then to search for a chat you can do:

```
SELECT * 
FROM messages AS m INNER JOIN add_friends as AF ON M.SENDER= AF.EMAIL1 
WHERE email_2 = '" + EMAIL_CONVERSION_WITH + "'"
```

You can achieve this in any language.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a user defined function passing it the sender & receiver - that function can check if a record of those emails exists in Add_Friends and if accepted_or_not = 1 and return BIT (0 / 1). Then you can use the function in a constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE [Messages1]
    WITH CHECK ADD CONSTRAINT [Your_Constraint_Name] 
    CHECK ([dbo].[Your_Function_Name]([sender], [reciever]) = 1)

ALTER TABLE [Messages1] CHECK CONSTRAINT [Your_Constraint_Name]
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having a column `accepted_or_not`in Add_Friends, you can define another table 'Friends_Accepted':

```
CREATE TABLE Friends_Accepted(

Id INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
email_canSend VARCHAR(50) FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Normal_Users,
email_canReceive VARCHAR(50) FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Normal_Users,
)
```

In this table, you would add TWO lines when a friend request is accepted -- one for each direction of the conversation: (A.Email,B.Email), (B.Email, A.Email)

Now you can have the table `Messages1` reference `Friends_Accepted`:

```
CREATE TABLE Messages1(

message_ID INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
date_sent date,
message_content VARCHAR(100),
fromTo_Id FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Friends_Accepted,
)
```

So a message from (A to B) and a message from (B to A) will reference two DIFFERENT lines in `Friends_Accepted`